# USA Road Network Data Set Options?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, traffic, openstreetmap

I need a contiguous, nationwide USA Road Network with speed limits, distances, etc. I have been using TIGER but the challenge is at state boundaries - where contiguous road segments are split.

Is there any free or commercially available data set that provides this data, besides ESRI/ArcGIS?

Comment: Could you better define what the issue is?

Comment: Most highway administration's definition of 'road'  or 'road segment' makes it difficult to track contiguous paths  .... a section was re-paved last year?  That's a new segment.  Re-aligned?  new segment.  Different road surface?  more than one segment.  Change in number of lanes?  More than one segment.  Some will track north & southbound lanes independently.   (this is based off a conversation I had w/ someone from a state agency last summer)

Answer (score 5):

[OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) hosts an open source google maps like database from which you can download all the map elements, from which you can filter all the roads according to the type of road you want. The speed limits should be tagged as described on [their wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Speed_limits).

Answer (score 3):

The National Transportation Atlas Database provides a roadway network and data to accomplish this:

- [NTAD Liner Notes](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2015/liner)
- [Highway Performance Monitoring System](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2014/zip/hpms.zip) - This includes data for speed limits (795 MB)
- [National Highway Planning Network](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/AdditionalAttachmentFiles/nhpn.zip) (173 MB) - This is the network used to tie data together.
- [National Transportation Atlas Databases 2015](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2015/index.html) - This includes additional polygon, polyline, and point data to make maps look good.